# Can I run clj file directly on emacs?

Tags: emacs, clojure

I'm using clojure-box on windows.

Because the Emacs is totally new thing for me, I got some trouble with using it.

1. Can I save the real code(without user>> and result, etc) from Emacs? it seems C-x C-s oversave many things..
2. how can I run the .clj script directly on Emacs? I'm from python so the way Idle running script is wonderful
   (just press F5, then script is excuted, then continue the REPL with having variables, functions in the script)
   Is there anyway to do thing easy like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes! emacs has several ways to do this. check out the emacs starter kit

People tend not to save the REPL as a whole.It is more common to paste parts of it into a normal Clojure buffer and then hit control-c control-l to load the buffer into the REPL. This keeps the REPL in synk with the file/buffer and will also print any output your script generates.

there is much more to using emacs with Clojure than I can express in one answer though the emacs starter kit is, well, a good place to start.